# Neo4j - casual cluster store copy failed

Tags: neo4j

Im trying to setup a fresh Neo4j casual cluster. Node 1 stated successfully and its waiting for other nodes to join.

When I start the node2 and 3, its failed due to store ID mismatch. I referred this ([Setting up Causal Cluster Fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50609521/setting-up-causal-cluster-fails)), but still its not working.  I don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me on this?

```
2020-01-16 11:26:00.130+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager]   Total size of mapped files: 112.00 kB
2020-01-16 11:26:00.130+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] --- STARTED diagnostics for KernelDiagnostics:StoreFiles END ---
2020-01-16 11:26:00.130+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.DatabaseHealth] Database health set to OK
2020-01-16 11:26:00.130+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Fulfilling of requirement 'Database is stopped' makes database graph.db available.
2020-01-16 11:26:00.131+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Database graph.db is ready.
2020-01-16 11:26:00.131+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.PageCacheWarmer] Page cache warmup started.
2020-01-16 11:26:00.131+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.PageCacheWarmer] Page cache warmup started.
2020-01-16 11:26:00.131+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.PageCacheWarmer] Page cache warmup started.
2020-01-16 11:26:00.131+0000 INFO [o.n.c.c.s.LocalDatabase] Stopping, reason: Database is stopped
2020-01-16 11:26:00.131+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Requirement `Database is stopped` makes database graph.db unavailable.
2020-01-16 11:26:00.131+0000 INFO [o.n.k.a.DatabaseAvailabilityGuard] Database graph.db is unavailable.
2020-01-16 11:26:00.151+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.PageCacheWarmer] Page cache warmup completed. 6 pages loaded. Duration: 19ms.
2020-01-16 11:26:00.161+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by "Database shutdown" @ txId: 1 checkpoint started...
2020-01-16 11:26:00.161+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.PageCacheWarmer] Page cache warmup completed. 6 pages loaded. Duration: 30ms.
2020-01-16 11:26:00.162+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.p.PageCacheWarmer] Page cache warmup completed. 6 pages loaded. Duration: 31ms.
2020-01-16 11:26:00.180+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.c.CheckPointerImpl] Checkpoint triggered by "Database shutdown" @ txId: 1 checkpoint completed in 19ms
2020-01-16 11:26:00.180+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.t.l.p.LogPruningImpl] No log version pruned, last checkpoint was made in version 0
2020-01-16 11:26:00.211+0000 ERROR [o.n.c.c.s.s.CoreStateDownloader] Store copy failed due to store ID mismatch
2020-01-16 11:26:04.219+0000 INFO [o.n.c.c.s.s.CoreStateDownloader] Recovering local database
2020-01-16 11:26:04.224+0000 INFO [o.n.c.c.s.LocalDatabase] Starting with storeId: Store{creationTime:1579172159723, randomId:-3096587090292784570, upgradeTime:1579172159723, upgradeId:1}
2020-01-16 11:26:04.228+0000 WARN [o.n.k.a.i.f.FulltextIndexProvider] Failed to register the fulltext index procedures. The fulltext index provider will be loaded and updated like normal, but it might not be possible to query any fulltext indexes. The reason given is: Unable to register procedure, because the name `db.index.fulltext.awaitEventuallyConsistentIndexRefresh` is already in use.
2020-01-16 11:26:04.298+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Selected RecordFormat:StandardV3_4[v0.A.9] record format from store /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db
2020-01-16 11:26:04.303+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Selected RecordFormat:StandardV3_4[v0.A.9] record format from store /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db
2020-01-16 11:26:04.303+0000 INFO [o.n.k.i.s.f.RecordFormatSelector] Format not configured. Selected format from the store: RecordFormat:StandardV3_4[v0.A.9]
2020-01-16 11:26:04.354+0000 INFO [o.n.k.NeoStoreDataSource] No commits found after last check point (which is at LogPosition{logVersion=0, byteOffset=16})
2020-01-16 11:26:04.371+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] --- STARTED diagnostics for KernelDiagnostics:Versions START ---
2020-01-16 11:26:04.371+0000 INFO [o.n.i.d.DiagnosticsManager] Graph Database: enterprise core StoreId{creationTime=1
```

Comment: try clearing the cluster-state file

Comment: Where to find the cluster state file?